# What is "σ" in a context free grammar?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I have a grammar like this:

```
A → BAB | B | ε
B → 00σ | ε
```

What is the meaning of σ in the second rule?

Comment: I think it's a symbol in the language.

Comment: There is no general meaning for this notation; you will need to consult your textbook or professor. We can only guess; either it's a terminal symbol in the language, or a nonterminal symbol, or as Dmitri guesses it means any character in alphabet $\Sigma$...

Comment: @6005, ... or a typo of some kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, it means “for each letter $\sigma$ from alphabet $\Sigma$”.

If $\Sigma = \{ 0, 1 \}$, then `B → 000 | 001 | ε`.